# C++. Help! How to make this program (using rand number generator) doesn't give out any duplicated number?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    int a [99];
    srand (time(NULL));

for(int i = 0; i <=9; i++)
{
    a[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;             // Random number range from 1 to 10.
    cout << "index # "<< i <<"\t"<<a[i] << " "<< endl;

    if(i != 0)                          /*to prevent a[0] and a[0] from             comparing each other*/
    {    
        int n = i - 1;                  //counter
        while( n!= -1)                  // to control the loop.
        {
            if(a[i] == a[n])
            {
                a[i] = rand() % 10 + 1; //reassign a random number to that index        location.
                n = i;                  //reset counter if there is a match number.
            }

            n--;                        //counts from the highest index No. to the lowest.
        }

    }

}

return 0;
}
```

ps:
To generate random numbers from 1 - 10.
It kept giving me duplicated numbers,
How can I make it not to duplicate the same numbers,
The while loop I used doesn't seem to work at all

Target Example Output would be like:
1
5
6
3
2
4
8
9
7
10

Instead of bunch of duplicated single digit numbers.

Comment: Please learn how to properly format your code!

Comment: put the numbers in a std::vector. std::random_shuffle the vector. take the first number then erase it so you don't get it again.

Comment: @user4581301 Taking the last number should be better because erasing the first number of `std::vector` will cost much.

Comment: @MikeCAT Your point sir. Salute!

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the result of the process to prevent duplicate numbers from printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    int a [99];

    srand (time(NULL));


    for(int i = 0; i <=9; i++)
    {

        a[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;             // Random number range from 1 to 10.


        // remove this
        //cout << "index # "<< i <<"\t"<<a[i] << " "<< endl;


        if(i != 0)                          /*to prevent a[0] and a[0] from             comparing each other*/
        {    
            int n = i - 1;                  //counter

            while( n!= -1)                  // to control the loop.
            {
                if(a[i] == a[n])
                {
                    a[i] = rand() % 10 + 1; //reassign a random number to that index        location.
                    n = i;                  //reset counter if there is a match number.
                }

                n--;                        //counts from the highest index No. to the lowest.
            }

        }

        // add this
        cout << a[i] << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```